# Can I use Wagtails API to power multiple sites from a single API endpoint?

Tags: api, wagtail, multiple-sites, headless-cms

In this example wagtail is deployed to cms.example.com and is managing content for foo.example.com and bar.example.com as a headless CMS.

When accessing the Pages API on cms.example.com/api/pages/ only the pages for the current active site (cms.example.com) are returned.

To get the content for the "foo" and "bar" sites cms.example.com/api/ also needs to be available as foo.example.com/api/ and bar.example.com/api/ (e.g. using a proxy).

Is it possible to query the API for pages from other sites without having to go through some proxy?

Answer (score 2):

Wagtail's API is a fairly thin layer on top of Django Rest Framework, and you should feel encouraged to customise it or roll your own.

Filtering pages by the current site happens [in the `PagesAPIEndpoint.get_queryset` method](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c9e740324c1a2197454274f5d18514b9a0752374/wagtail/api/v2/endpoints.py#L427-L432), and the simplest way of disabling that behaviour would be to subclass `PagesAPIEndpoint` to override that method, and register your custom subclass in urls.py in place of the original.

Comment: That would involve copying the entire body of `get_queryset`, something I'd like to avoid for maintainability. There's also the `child`/`descendant_of` filters, they are also restricted to the current site. It would be nice if I could somehow override `request.site`, other than accessing the site through a different hostname (e.g. some Param or header)

Comment: It seems much easier to write a custom `SiteMiddleware` that uses [`get_site_for_hostname`](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/c9e740324c1a2197454274f5d18514b9a0752374/wagtail/core/sites.py#L10) to set the current site based on something other than the current hostname

Comment: In your case you don't have to copy the entire body of `get_queryset`. You have to replace it with `return Page.objects.all().public().live()` which afaik does what you need.